# Как узнать название класса из статик метода в java?

Tags: android, java

Как узнать название класса из статик метода в java

```
public String tag = this.getLocalClassName();
```

Делаю так, но он годится только для не статик метода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936684/getting-the-class-name-from-a-static-method-in-java), должно помочь. Скорее всего, все упирается в this, из-за того что метод статичный.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что надо, а еще проблема в том, что  от этого класса наследуются другие классы, и мне нужно, чтобы в этом классе хранилось имя дочернего класса, а не родителя. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: @eldqs, а вы создайте метод getClassName, который переопределяйте в дочерних классах

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как это относится к Андроиду, поэтому напишу, как получить имя класса, даже если этот метод статический.

```
class A{

    public A() {
        String name=getClassName(this.getClass());
    }
    public static String getClassName(Class<?> clazz){
        return clazz.getName();
    }
}
```

Ну я нигде не упоминал имя класса явно. Однако можно указать его явно и избеждать писанины. Я же вижу, из какого класса я вызываю этот метод. Поэтому я пишу имя. 
Класс, в котором находится метод:

```
class A{

    public A() {
    }
    public static String getClassName(){
        return A.class.getCanonicalName();
    }
}
```

`getCanonicalName()`, или `getName()`, или `getSimpleName()` - я думаю, сам разберёшься, какой тебе нужен.

**Вариант первого способа:**

```
class A{

    public A() {
        String name=getClassName(this);
    }
    public static String getClassName(Object ob){
        return ob.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это то, что мне нужно, но я не понял, как мне вызывать этот метод, что мне ему передавать надо: 
    
    public static String getClassName(Class<?> clazz){
        return clazz.getName();
    }

Comment: у каждого объекта есть метод `.getClass()`. абсолютно у каждого. Он возвращает объект класса `Class<?>` (не забивай голову если непонятно) . Просто отправляй тот метод `любойОбъект.getClass`. PS добавил ещё способ. посмотри на пост

Comment: @argamidon но дело в том, что эта переменная должна быть статическая и позже наследоваться, и когда она наследуется, у нее должно быть имя дочернего класса в статической переменной, `static String tag =getClassName(this);` не подходит, потому что String static.